# Amazon EC or 'standard' VPS for web hosting?

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, vps, cloud-hosting

I'm looking at the Amazon EC for a small Linux hosting setup of up to a dozen site that I want decent performance for standard PHP/MySQL sites. I would like opinions about the value-for-money of Amazon's service when considering:

1. speed of response/page load ...
2. cost ...
3. ease of setup/maintenance...

... in comparison to other similar priced Linux VPS hosting setups.

I understand scalability is a big bonus with Amazon, but I'm more interested in the above 3 factors.

Comment: I would suggest a VPS. EC2 is designed more for utility computing than running a Web site. This post maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703052/need-some-help-choosing-between-amazon-ec2-and-vps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon EC2 / cloud is mostly relevant if you need on-demand, scalable infrastructure. Your analysis seems to be more of a "what's in the box" query, which is more relevant to a VPS vs. VPS analysis.

But since you ask:

1) **Speed:** It's a bit like asking how long is a piece of string... Are you interested in IO, BW, inter-server comms etc.? Anyway, with EC2 you are paying for a box that's as large as you need. So in theory any problems with the physical speed of the box can be alleviated by just procuring larger EC2 hardware.

2) **Cost:** Linked to item number 1. Need a really big box and you'll be paying several dollars per hour. We actually run a relatively large business using only the 'Small' box instances, which cost us about 10 cents/hr. In general EC2 may have a higher annual cost than a fixed term VPS lease (which makes sense, cause EC2 is about on-demand infrastructure and not fixed infrastructure).

3) **Setup:** My personal opinion is that EC2 can be a challenge to get used to on first contact. It may also require some understand of security (pub/priv keys) and scripting. But once understood, it's actually a pretty neat infrastructure to use and maintain.

We actually had a recent set of blog entries that may be of interest:

http://blog.labslice.com/2010/11/cloud-vs-vps-vs-shared-hosting.html
http://blog.labslice.com/2010/11/when-is-cloud-suitable-for-basic.html
http://blog.labslice.com/2010/11/why-your-business-really-needs-cloud.html